# Porting bat code to powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, mercurial, batch-file

Porting my bat scripts to PowerShell. Two problems: `$info` expands in strings like `"$info"`; when running commands from a file somewhere spoil the arguments (in interactive mode appears only the first problem. the console output "hg tip: invalid arguments").

Command:

```
hg tip --template "<?php\r\n// ќв®  ўв®¬ вЁзҐбЄЁ бЈҐ­ҐаЁа®ў ­­л© д ©« б Ё­д®а¬ жЁҐ© ® вҐЄгйҐ¬ ЎЁ«¤Ґ ¬®¤г«п\r\n$info = array(\r\n'rev' => '{rev}',\r\n'date' => '{date|isodate}',\r\n'changeset' => '{node}',\r\n);" > modules/video/version.php
```

Comment: In the end, everything was decided:
1) Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9149466/1115601
2) The problem was due to a specific text encoding (Cyrillic in the DOS encoding). Here it is: `ќв®  ўв®¬ вЁзҐбЄЁ бЈҐ­ҐаЁа®ў ­­л© д ©« б Ё­д®а¬ жЁҐ© ® вҐЄгйҐ¬ ЎЁ«¤Ґ ¬®¤г«п`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to not evaluate `$info` as variable you must write it as `` `$info ``. Like:

```
 hg tip --template "<?php\r\n// ќв®  ўв®¬ вЁзҐбЄЁ бЈҐ®ў © д ©« б Ё®а¬ жЁҐ© ® вҐЄгйҐ¬ ЎЁ«¤Ґ ¬®¤г«п\r\n`$info = array(\r\n'rev' => '{rev}',\r\n'date' => '{date|isodate}',\r\n'changeset' => '{node}',\r\n);" > modules/video/version.php
```

$ is powershell keyword therefore `$

Answer (score 2):

Also, another way is to use single-quotes  instead of double quotes you are using now.

update:

Ok, so basically you have 3 approaches.

- Single-quotes - Expressions are not evaluated. But you need to escape the single-quote sign.
- Double-quotes - Expressions are evaluated. So, if you want to use $ sign you need to escape it.
- Here-strings - Either single, or double-quotes (evaluated/not evaluated). Strings can span multiple lines. You don't need to escape anything if you use single quote approach

Example for third approach:

```
[12:06:58 PM] ~> $str = @'
'$'`#'"<>\/@
'@ 


_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
[12:07:15 PM] ~> $str
'$'`#'"<>\/@
```

Comment: Can you fix my code? I've pretty much tried, in the end made ​​this a separate line in bat file.